# Auto import not working for Android classes in Android studio

Tags: android-studio, import, android-sdk-tools

I am working on a project in Android studio. Suddenly, auto import stopped working in android studio for Android classes, like Android.widgets.Textview, etc. In my settings, auto import is enabled. If I write import android.widget.textview, then TextView shows up in the auto import box.

Comment: Try option + enter if you are using Android Studio on MacOSX

Comment: Only for android.xxxxx.xxxxxx i have to copy -paste import lines

Answer (score 89, accepted):

The problem was with android studio indexing.

Follow the steps..

Go to 'File' > 'Invalidate caches/restart'

Now the studio will shut down and restart. Now indexing begins. On completion of indexing you will find the Suggestion boxes with every possible suggestions.

Comment: bravo! what a weird issue for a "stable" beta ide

Comment: Not mine. Just ask me to implement the class

Comment: Invalidate/restart wasn't working, somehow the "Add unambiguous imports on the fly" was unchecked despite it working not 2-3 updates ago. Ticked the box and now it's working again.

Comment: Windows 10, Android Studio 2.3.3 - not help

Comment: thanks so much, i am using android studio 3.0.1 and the auto import still doesnt work as intended

Comment: Nice , Worked for me

Answer (score 12):

For me, the problem was that "Show import popup" was not checked at File > Settings > Editor > General > Auto Import > Java.

Comment: thanks for location. my problem was Excluding import android.widget.* and removing this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me the reason was that the class I tried to create did **not** have an explicit **public** keyword, which made the class private by default, so it didn't show up in the import context menu of android studio.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that Gradle targetSdkVersion 30 and compileSdkVersion 30.
I changed that at targetSdkVersion 31 and compileSdkVersion 31. And works again.
I have tried two days to resolve this issue. And voilà!

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was missing lines in to build.gradle (app)

```
plugins {
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that Power Save Mode was on for some weird reason.

**Solution:**

Disable "Power Save Mode" in Android Studio menu: File->Power Save Mode

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem here, in my case I think it happen because i forced renaming my flutter projects. And unfortunetly when i realize, i forgot the actual name before i renaming.

But it solve by push to git, then download again the project, reopen with android studio. Voila, it solve. It may stupid way to solve, but it work.

I think it happen because Android studio generated file in project to save setting for each project. But after i rename my folder, the connection between  apps and setting file is broken.