# Unable to import basic Android librarys to my project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, import, android-library

No problems for a long time at all, but now suddenly I am not able to make simple imports to my classes, se for example:

[image]

I've tried to restart Android Studio, clean the project, tried to reinstall android studio... But nothings seems to fix this.

I think the problem started after copying an XML layout file into this project from another project. However, I checked the file many times and there's nothing wrong with it... no red flag or lines. Other imports that I did before this are still there and working (like Drawable, View, TextView...)

Any ides? Thank you!

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24406225/auto-import-not-working-for-android-classes-in-android-studio

Comment: Wonderful! The File -> Invalidate caches / Restart made it work again. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio:
File -> Invalidate caches / Restart made it work again