# Android Studio can not find necessary imports

Tags: android, import

The problem is that the IDE does not suggest any classes to import while typing class name. However, if I manually type, for example, `import android.widget.Button;` the error with finding the class disappeares. All checkboxes in the Auto Import are ticked. Thank you.

Comment: i think this answer will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/a/24406882/4967569

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this!

File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart -> Invalidate and Restart