# Android studio doesn't suggest import

Tags: android, android-studio

Android studio is failing to suggest imports for known classes, like Date and List and so on. Just warns "Cannot resolve symbol"

```
Android Studio 2.2.3
Build #AI-145.3537739, built on December 2, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_76-release-b03 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

Note: Auto import is enabled, and there are no excluded classes from it, manually adding the *import* statement works.

Comment: Does gradle give you errors? If it does, solve those first. Are there errors elsewhere in your app? If so, try to solve those first.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should automatically import (atleast in 2.2.2).Try this if it does not,
Select the red coloured text ( the symbols which can't be resolved) and press `Ctrl+i` . This will import the required.

If this does not work go to `File-> Invalidate caches/Restart.`

[Auto import not working for Android classes in Android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24406225/auto-import-not-working-for-android-classes-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Invalidating caches didn't work for me.

What I found working was to tick the "Scope analysis to the current package" in the Dart Analysis.

[image]