# Android Studio does not automatically import androidx.lifecycle.observe

Tags: android, android-studio, android-lifecycle

When I put the following code in the Android Studio, Android Studio does not prompt me to import `observe` from `androidx.lifecycle`. I have to manually do the import and I am starting to get tired of it.

```
        startFragmentViewModel.suggestions.observe(this) {
            it?.let { searchView.addSuggestions(it) }
        }
```

Supposing we write a function like so:

```
//fun Fragment.importObserve() {
//    import androidx.lifecycle.observe
//}
```

Is there a way we can do something like that?

Comment: This question answers your question quite well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24406225/auto-import-not-working-for-android-classes-in-android-studio

Comment: @Dango3 I checked out the link, it doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

Due to [the issue reported here](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1413815/1), this is actually normal behavior, as when moving to Kotlin 1.4 or above, `androidx.lifecycle.observe` will be deprecated, and you can use in-build `observe` extension function instead.

The opposed behavior (auto adding the import) is actually not recommended.